# Consistency checks in dbt Cloud

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, dbt

The goal is to compare the data in the dataset source with the data after cleaning, modelling and ingesting it into the data warehouse and send an alert in case of mismatch.
Is this possible with dbt Cloud or I should use Python

Answer (score 0):

If by "source" you mean a different database, before it is ingested into your data warehouse, I'd recommend using [datadiff](https://github.com/datafold/data-diff).

Once the data is in your warehouse, you can use dbt to compare two different tables (let's say in your raw or source schema and your final modeled schema).

There are quite a few tests in [dbt-utils](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#generic-tests) for this. You may also be interested in [dbt-expectations](https://github.com/calogica/dbt-expectations) if you need more powerful or complex tests.